# Excel VBA equivalent of a vector

Tags: excel, vba

Does Excel VBA have a data structure equivalent of the vector?

I am still learning Excel VBA and do not like the `ReDim Preserve` semantics. But if that is the only way, then so be it.

So does Excel VBA 2003 provide a dynamic list type data structure?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand correctly you question, that why a delete my comment. I am only familiar with the ReDim semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple sequential `list`-datatype would be `Collection`. Besides, an associative array is available via `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.

```
Dim c As Collection
Set c = New Collection
c.Add 4
```

Comment: +1 and just to elaborate the `collection` object has a `key` field but it doesn't do what you'd expect. Hence the `Dictionary` object, which is available via late binding like you describe but also available though early binding through the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference.

Comment: used this method. i guess this is as close as it gets to vectors